# surface integral, parametrisation

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Let $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\leq1,z=1+xy+x^2\}$. Now I want to calculate $\int_S<V,n>do$ for a given $V$. For this I need to calculate the normal unit vector. To get the direction I can take the gradient of $f=z-1-xy-x^2$. The proper way is to use the ‎parameterisation $p=(x,y,1+xy+x^2)$ and just take the appropriate cross product. Now in this case it happens that the gradient of $f$ allready has the correct magnitude.

My question: Is there a (usable) parametrisation $P$ for a given surface (submanifold) $S$ for which the magnitude of $\nabla f$ is allready "correct" (i.e. if $f^{-1}(0)=S=P(A)$ then $\int_S<V,n>do=\int_A<V\circ P,\nabla f\circ P>d\mu$ for a given $V$)?

Maybe this is trivial or very badly written, if so let me know so I can edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard formula for a vector normal to the surface is:

$dS = $$<-\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}, 1> \:dx \:dy\\
<-y-2x,-x,1>\: dx \:dy$

And then since this is a surface bound by a cylinder, it is likely that you will what to covert to cylindrical.

$r<-r\sin t-2r \cos t,-r \cos t,1>\: dr \:dt$

Whether you actually need to unitize it depends on the problem.  Usually you don't.

Comment: Given a parametrisation, in what cases would it be possible to deduce the magnitude of the area element from the gradient of $f$? ($f$ as above) This $dS$ only works in this special case.

Comment: Almost always, $\iint V\cdot n \| dS \| dA = \iint (V\cdot  dS)  dA =$

Comment: What I ment is that usually one cannot easily parameterize a general $S$ with $p(u,v,w)=(u,v,g(u,v))$, and only in this case (and its permutations) we can use this $dS$. Of course it exist (if $0$ is a regular value of $f$), but to actually do calculations with it would be difficult in some (most?) cases. I think I asked my question wrong, I kind of can't explain what I'm asking for...